# JSF - Extensive Read-Write to Application-Scoped Bean

Tags: jsf, javabeans, lotus-notes, xpages

In my XPages web app (Xpages a Lotus Notes Technology based in JSF), I need to have a dynamic map to store the session IDs and the last accessed time (in millisecond). This is implemented as a `TreeMap` inside a application-scoped bean. Each initial access to the app registers the current session to the TreeMap in this bean. Only a limited number of session entries are permitted to this map, and excess sessions are not registered. The map is also cleared once in a while from old session entries so that new sessions can be registered.  **I need to know if this is an acceptable approach/use of a application bean.** I know I can store the session entries temporarily in an external DB (non-lotus notes) but the company I'm working for doesn't allow me to do so. Will this approach lead me to potential problems? If yes, is there another way for me to do this?

Comment: This seems absolutely legal to me. This is a perfect use case for a application scoped bean IMO. I would prefer to store it in a db though.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a perfectly valid use of an application bean, but I'd offer two suggestions. The first is to use a ConcurrentSkipListMap instead of a TreeMap. The former is thread-safe, while the latter is not. When interacting with the lower scopes, thread safety is typically not crucial, as each user can only write to their own session, view, and request scopes, but all users can write to the application scope, so it's conceivable that concurrent writes could occur, especially in applications with heavy user load. The second suggestion is to urge caution with how much information about each session is stored in an application bean. Since the bean will be accessible to all users, it is theoretically possible to inadvertently expose too much information about a user to other users. If you're only storing session name or ID in addition to the last access time, you'll be fine. But if you're actually storing a pointer to each user's session scope, you may accidentally provide a window into data a user has cached that other users shouldn't have access to. I've never actually seen someone get bitten by this, but it's always important to keep this in mind when storing any user-specific information in the application scope.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this is a good use of the Application Scope. Still, the `TreeMap` collection isn't the best approach for your situation, there are some problems with this:

- Concurrency problems when 2 requests want to modify the data in your container.
- If your application must scale horizontally, you will have 2 `TreeMap`s in each managed bean.

A good approach will be using a cache system. There are good cache libraries that will meet these requirements, I've tested [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/get-started/introduction)  and it provides both concurrent management for handling data and libraries in case you have 2 or more nodes to deploy your application, also you can configure an algorithm to clear the cache based on  LRU (less frequently used) or FIFO (first in, first out).

Using an external database to handle the sessions IDs could consume some time to get/set the data (it could be very low, but still it is a disk I/O operation). For that problem, you can use [BigMemory](http://ehcache.org/documentation/bigmemory/index) as an external database that lives in RAM, or a NoSQL database like [BigTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable).

Note: I do not work for ehcache nor I'm associated in a commercial way, I've tested it and it fulfills my needs.,Tthere are other cache system libraries like [JBoss Cache](http://www.jboss.org/jbosscache/) and [others](http://java-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions) you can evaluate and use.